# python prints the output two times

Tags: python-3.x

My python code prints the output twice.

I can't print the output correctly. Kindly help. Thanks in advance

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
        if len(fname) < 1 : 
           fname = "mbox-short.txt"

        fh = open(fname)
        count = 0

        for ln in fh:
            if ln.startswith("From"):
               count = count + 1
               b2 = ln.split()
               print(b2[1])

        print("There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

Comment: Hi Manisha, can you please provide the output?

Comment: add sample input and expected output

Comment: Your question is not clear, enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use print(b[0]) in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code on pycharm, with a file **abc.txt** having content:

```
From dhfgdfjdfvdf dfd f
from bjddfgdhgfkdgfkd
dhdgfdhfgj
dfhdgfgdhfg
From hgfdfgdgsdguig
```

and got this as result:

```
Enter file name: 
dhfgdfjdfvdf
hgfdfgdgsdguig
There were 2 lines in the file with From as the first word
```

So as per the code there are no two final outputs, and I assuming that

```
print(b2[1])
```

is intentional.